# How does @Deployment work in an Arquillian test?

Tags: jboss-arquillian, shrinkwrap

How does [(JBoss) Shrinkwrap](http://www.jboss.org/shrinkwrap) perform the deployment of a war file in the container when I use the @Deployment annotation in an Arquillian test?

Answer (score 2):

As John said, it really depends on how container adapter is implemented (in particular the deployment automation bits). I case of WebSphere container adapter it's using SOAP admin client available from WAS, Glassfish stuff works through their REST api and so on.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on your container, not all containers will do it the same way.